# Probability of 6 teams winning an 8 team debating competition

Tags: combinatorics

My son is in a debating team that competes in an 8 team round robin competition. Each team every other team once, and the result is a win or a loss (no draws).

This year 6 teams came equal first, which was claimed to be a rare event. The question is how rare?

It is relatively easy to show that there are 2^28 = 268435456 possible outcomes, and that 8 teams cannot come equal first.

I also established by exhaustive search that of the total number of outcomes for 
* 1 team first is 160,241,151 = 59.694%
* 2 teams first is 73,565,184 = 27.405%
* 3 teams first is 22,980,609 = 8.561%
* 4 teams first is 5,111,681 = 1.904%
* 5 teams first is 5,212,033 = 1.942% (higher than 4 teams first)
* 6 teams first is 1,303,678 = 0.486%
* 7 teams first is 21,120 = 0.008%

This indicates that the probability of my son's team's outcome is less than 0.486% because all teams are not equal.

However, I would be interested in a closed form solution of the above problem. Any takers?

Comment: Each team competes in $7$ matches, so there are $28$ total matches.  The six winners must each win $4$ and lose $3$, accounting for $24$ of the wins.  In the round robin between the winners, there were $15$ matches, so the winners took $9$ of $12$ from the losers.  I don't see a nice way to characterize the desired outcomes, though.

Comment: Actually, the fact that all teams are not equal can improve the chances of a 6-way tie for first:  Say two specific teams are very slightly worse than the other 6, which are all equal.  Then the enhancement of the cases where those two teams are the losers will outweigh the decrease in probability of the cases where one or both of those teams is a winner.